# RandomForestRegressor: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This is for a project that's due soon so help would be greatly appreciated, I've never done ML before so sorry if the mistake is an absolute smooth brain one.

I have a dataset that's a bunch of tweets along with personality scores, and I need to train an model to predict the scores.
This is what I've done so far by following a bunch of tutorials and stitching together what I learned.

```
train = pandas.read_csv('../dataset/cleaner_dataset.csv')
train['tweet'] = train['tweet'].str.lower()
train['tweet'] = train['tweet'].replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', regex = True)

X = train['tweet']
y = train['neuroticism']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5)
X_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5)
X_test_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train) 

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_vectorized, y_train)

model.score(X_test_vec, y_test)
```

However I'm getting an error on the last line of code when I run it in the notebook.

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [495, 1980]
```

Full error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cff5w.jpg

Comment: Can you share the dataset with us so that we can try to solve the problem?

Comment: As the answer below points out, you have a **typo** - you vectorize `X_train` a second time instead of `X_test`. But notice the comment in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

you are using x_train for both train and test and is the reason you are getting the error.

try:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=5)
X_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)

X_test_vec = vectorizer.transform(X_test) # use the same vectorizer, do not define a new one
```

As pointed out below, we dont fit the test set.
BUT* you still need to use the X_test with y_test

Comment: We do **not** use `fit_transform` on the *test* set; we only use `transform` with the vectorizer already fitted on the training set (yes, you have spotted the **typo** in the question, but this is not the correct remedy).

Comment: Instead of providing puzzling verbal clarifications (I have not said that we don't *vectorize* the test set!), please **correct** the code to `X_test_vec = vectorizer.transform(X_test)` and remove the 2nd vectorizer definition.

Comment: My bad. You're right. Edited.